# IP Based User Authorization in MVC4

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

We have an MVC application which we need to do some security check before we let user to start using system. The use case is below;

We have Company table which stores valid IP addresses(also range). And company has associated users. If a user logs in from an unidentified email address, we need to make sure that user is still working for corresponding company. Therefore, we use company email address to validate the user.

I have 2 ways to implement this;

1) Generate a token, and send a link with token as query string to the user, when user clicks on this link, I will validate the user for a certain period of time(1 day)

2) Sending user's email a 6 digit number when user successfully logs in, and ask user to enter that pin number. If the pin is valid, then validate the user.

I recently see many big companies using pin numbers and your mobile no. That made me think that the second method is more secure than the first one(I have no facts, only assumption). Is that true?

Which one of these methods is more secure? if non of them, what is the best way of implementing this use case.

Thanks

Comment: How can they log on from an unidentified email address? (do you mean IP?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [IP spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) - I wouldn't recommend using IP addresses for security.

1) - I don't understand how that is secure...

2) - called [two factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step_verification) and would typically involve sending a pin to a mobile, and not an email.

If implemented properly 2) should be secure, but that is an additional step and not a complete security model. I would start by looking at the [authentication that is part of MVC5](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/09/authentication-filters-aspnetmvc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you please recommend 3rd solution? how would you implement this?

Comment: I don't know the requirements, but I'd probably use the built-in security with MVC5. If 2) is required, the built-in security could be augmented to include that step.

Comment: The application developed with MVC4. We do have a complete authorized user security model which was penetration tested by a professional security company. The issue is to identify users from different IP addresses, and put another security measure between these steps. you said you would not use the IP address for the security, what would you use in this case?

Comment: Don't your users have an email address and password for authentication? I don't understand what the IP address has to do with it. That's probably because I don't know the background. If you look at OWIN (with MVC5) that deals with organisations, not just users.

Comment: Right, here is the use case. we have a customer which has a user accessing to our system. then this user leaves the company, but our customer forget to deactivate his/her account. and user goes to home, or to another place, but still have access to the system because his account has not been deactivated. I need to prevent such  case. I thought, if I have a list of valid IP addresses(customer sites), I can trust logins from these ip addresses. if user tries to login from a different location, I can identify and put some checks.  but you say, you would not use IP address for security.

Comment: does above comment give more info?

Comment: Ok, I understand. What about ensuring the password has to be reset regularly - via an email.  If the user has left the company they wouldn't be able to get the email?

Comment: For instance, how google knows that I am logging in from different device or location? isnt it IP address? or Geo location?

Comment: Ok, so you wouldn't be relying on the IP address for security. But simply if the user had a different IP address the last time they logged-in the system sends a text message to ensure they are authenticated. Yes, that makes sense and is two-step authentication.

Comment: You could also get browser version, language, operating system, time zone details with the IP address and store that with each email address. It will be quite annoying for users - everytime they change devices...

Comment: The system also relies on the user not using a personal phone, only a work one... Is that realistic, and how would it be controlled?

Comment: I am getting back to the question before I answer this, you said you dont understand how option 1 is secure. if we store generated token in the database and validate user with the link, where do you see the problem with this?

Comment: I would use email addresses to send pin rather than email address, that is the only option I have at the moment for two-way authentication.

Comment: Ok, yes it makes more sense now.

Comment: So using token and sending link seems to be a solution as well then?

Comment: What stops that url being sent to someone else and someone else using it?

Comment: even if you have that URL, you will still need to login with your credentials. So, having that URL will not be enough to login to system.

Comment: But the guy who has left the company will know the credentials. Isn't sending an email better because if they have left they will not get the mail? Option 2)....

Comment: IP spoofing isn't a real concern for web application security as the attacker will never receive the TCP reply packets and cannot establish a connection.

Comment: @SilverlightFox - can you please post a link for showing that IP spoofing is of no concern for a web application - http and https?

Comment: Sure: [Can I trust the source IP of an HTTP request?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14505/8340)

Comment: But the question says "disregarding Man in the middle (MITM) attacks"... I would have thought a Man in the middle attack does make IP addresses insecure?

Comment: In a practical sense this would only be possible on a local network (spoofing an internal IP). Over the internet it would be far too complex to accomplish.

Comment: Also don't forget to include @SilverlightFox to alert me of responses - I only saw your last one by chance. Thanks!

Comment: @SilverlightFox - only possible on an internal network? What about WIFI?

Comment: Only if an internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a jump start on two factor authentication without building a solution from scratch, look at [this](http://brockallen.com/2013/07/29/announcing-membershipreboot/) open source framework that can easily integrate into an MVC4 application. As Joe R mentioned, relying on IPs for security is not a standard practice.